# how delete all rows with no SQL

Tags: java, sql-delete, ebean

Is the any other way to delete all rows of a database table without writing an SQL delete statement?

```
List<Item> items = Ebean.find(Item.class).findList();
Ebean.delete(items);
```

Is there anything like

```
Ebean.deleteAll(Item.class)
```

in Ebean API?

Comment: But if even if you're using [EBean](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery_rawsql.html), you can't get much simpler/much more efficient than a rawSql "delete from mytable" or "truncate myTable".  IMHO...

Comment: What I usually do if methods are lacking is I create a MyEbean utility class and put all the methods I find lacking in there.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed it exists, [check this out](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Ebean.html#delete%28java.util.Collection%29)

> Delete all the beans from a Collection.

```
public static int delete(Collection<?> c)
                  throws javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException
```

Comment: I can't get the link to load; does this actually delete the records from the DB, or just the entities in the model?

Comment: accidentally posted above comment as an answer earlier today. It was meant as a comment for @Victor